# I want to upload code written in HTML on a live website using GitHub

Tags: html, github

I am writing a simple SQL code within the body of the HTML code in Notepad. I have saved the Notepad file as .html in a folder. Now I want others to see the code in the website only. How it looks like altogether.

So in the process of that I opened an account on GitHub and downloaded the GitHub desktop application. I cloned a repository of the file where the code is there. The next processes to deploy the code in website is unknown to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>QUICK SQL CODE</title>
</head>
<body>
create table departments (
    id                             numeric(10) not null,
    name                           varchar2(255) not null,
    location                       varchar2(4000),
    country                        varchar2(4000),
    CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
<br>
<br>


create table employees (
    department_id                  number
                                   constraint employees_department_id_fk
                                   references departments on delete cascade,
    name                           varchar2(50) not null,
    email                          varchar2(255),
    cost_center                    number,
    date_hired                     date,
    job                            varchar2(255)
) ;

insert into departments (
    id,
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
     '1',
    'Security',
    'Tanquecitos',
    'United States'
);
<br>
<br>

insert into departments (
    id,
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
     '2',
    'Travel',
    'Sugarloaf',
    'United States'
)
;

<br>
<br>


insert into departments (
    id,
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    '3',
    'Office of the CEO',
    'Dale City',
    'United States'
);

<br>
<br>


insert into departments (
    id,
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    '4',
    'Security',
    'Grosvenor',
    'United States'
);

<br>
<br>
commit;

<br>

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Gricelda Luebbers',
    'gricelda.luebbers@aaab.com',
    20,
    sysdate - 94,
    'Systems Designer'
);

<br>
<br>

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Dean Bollich',
    'dean.bollich@aaac.com',
    11,
    sysdate - 74,
    'Legal Assistant'
);

<br>
<br>

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Milo Manoni',
    'milo.manoni@aaad.com',
    21,
    sysdate - 68,
    'Systems Designer'
);

<br>
<br>

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Laurice Karl',
    'laurice.karl@aaae.com',
    78,
    sysdate - 73,
    'Programmer'
)
;

<br>
<br>

select
    departments.name                                   department_name,
    departments.location                               location,
    departments.country                                country,
    employees.name                                     employee_name,
    employees.email                                    email,
    employees.cost_center                              cost_center,
    employees.date_hired                               date_hired,
    employees.job                                      job
from
    departments,
    employees;
<br>
<br>


commit;

<br>
<br>

OUTPUT :

Table created.

<br>
<br>

Table created.

<br>
<br>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br>
<br>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br/>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br>
<br>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br>
<br>

Statement processed.

<br>
<br>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br/>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br>
<br>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br>
<br>

1 row(s) inserted.

<br>
<br>

<h2>OUTPUT OF THE TABLE</h2>

<img src ='C:\Users\Saumyojit\Desktop\oracle sql live\output of experiment 1 id pkey.png'>

</body>
</html>
```

How will I upload it on a live website?

Comment: See https://pages.github.com/

Comment: @NullDev — They only support static pages.

Comment: Your question is massively too broad. You need to (a) Either run your SQL against a database manually or do it with a programming language. You can't just paste SQL into an HTML document to make it run. and (b) You need to find a host for your website (i.e. someone who will provide you with an HTTP server and database server. Github is for sharing code (although they have a feature for hosting static websites (not ones which need to execute SQL).

Comment: @Quentin I am aware. As far as I understood, the OP wants to upload those code snippets to a static HTML site hosted by GitHub, and doesn't want to actually execute them. That would be possible.

Comment: The question isn't really clear

Comment: I don't want to execute the code ,I just want it to get uploaded on a live website . I opened a account on GitHub. I have only one file of this HTML code nothing fancy about it which I wrote it in notepad and saved as . HTML . The name of the folder is quick sql. **Will I have to save it as index.html?** If yes then how will I upload it to live website . Plzz give me a link to some genuine you tube video so that I can do it. I have also Linked netlify with GitHub

Comment: How will i push if I have GitHub desktop. I have the git hub desktop app . My repository name is quick sql live . that's it

Comment: @Quentin  Will  i have to keep a index.html file in the folder?. Actually i have only one file only which has the above code saved as sql.html. I want this **one file only(sql.html) to be uploaded on the live website through github** .  THere is no other files like css or php .I have done nothing fancy.  **only 1 html notepad file**

Answer (score 0):

Your website have [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) or some other hosting software. This kind of software is used by hosting providers. So ask your hosting provider or your client to give you credentials and after login please find the destination folder where your website is hosted.

After that you can place this file in the root directory or any other sub folder as per your need.

- [cPanel](https://cpanel.net/)
- [Web Hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service)

Comment: Will I have to keep a index.html file in the folder?. Actually i have only one file only which has the above code saved as sql.html. I want this **one file only(sql.html) to be uploaded on the live website through github** .  THere is no other files like css or php .I have done nothing fancy.  **only 1 html notepad file** @Tabraiz

Comment: Not required index.html file. You can upload your file to server and can access via http://yourdomain.com/sql.html